# How to maintain reference to old values in a property

Tags: c#, list, reference

I have two variables, State and Address.
Depending on a condition, the value of State will = the value of Address. The problem I am having is maintaining a reference to State's previous value. I will need State's original value, should the condition change. As of now, my application cannot maintain a reference to old values.

Some more detail:
The data I am dealing with is Accounts and People (properties: Name, State, Address, Email) associated with these Accounts.

The data is displayed in a Matrix and the values are dependent on the aforementioned condition. The condition is which Account we are dealing with.

When there is a single Account, the value of State will = the value of Address. However, when there are more than 1 Accounts, the value of State will be unique.

The user can toggle between 4 Accounts. There can be multiple Accounts set at a time.

The problem is if I am dealing with a single Account and the State value becomes the Address value, I am not able to stash the old State value. The original State value will be used if there are more than 1 Account. When I have multiple Accounts, however, the State value is still = to the Address value. This is not ideal.

This is what I am looking for:

Example

Original Data = {"Ken, "WA", "123 St.", "Ken@email.com"}

Single Account

```
Name State Address Email
"Ken" "WA" "WA"    "Ken@email.com"
```

Multiple Accounts

```
 Name State Address Email
 "Ken" "WA" "123 St." "Ken@email.com"
```

However, this is what I am getting:

Single Account - FINE

```
Name State Address Email
"Ken" "WA" "WA"    "Ken@email.com"
```

Multiple Accounts - BAD

```
 Name State Address Email
 "Ken" "WA" "WA "Ken@email.com"
```

It is not cycling the value back

This is my code:

```
private void RefreshData()
{
  List<string> states = new List<string>();
  People.ForEach(p => states.Add(p.State)); // Attempting to stash current State vaues
  bool singleAccount = Accounts.Where(a => a.IsActive).Count() == 1;
  if (singleAccount)
  {
    int singleAccount = Accounts.IndexOf(Accounts.Where(a => a.IsActive).FirstOrDefault()) + 1; // Accounts are 1, 2, 3, or 4. I need the data for specific Account #s when a single Account
   AssignStateToAddress(states, singleAccount);
  }
  else
  {
    // Use the original values here, since there are multiple Accounts.
  }
 }


private void AssignStateToAddress(List<string> States, int singleAccount)
 {
   int position = 0;
   switch (singleAccount)
   {
     case 1: People.ForEach(p => p.Address1 = States[position++]);
      break;
     case 2: People.ForEach(p => p.Address2 = States[position++]);
      break;
     case 3: People.ForEach(p => p.Address3 = States[position++]);
      break;
     default: People.ForEach(p => p.Address4 = States[position++]);
      break;
    }
   }
  }
 }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the OOP concept of [encapsulation](https://stackify.com/oop-concept-for-beginners-what-is-encapsulation/), this type of logic should probably be handled internally by your `People` class. There are several ways you could handle it, but probably the easiest is to make `Address` a method that understands the desired behavior.

```cs
public class People
{
    public string State { get; set; }

    private string _address;

    public void SetAddress(string address)
        => _address = address;

    public void GetAddress(bool forSingleAccount)
        => forSingleAccount ? State : _address;
}
```

This way "it just works" when you call `GetAddress`.

If you *really* need `Address` to be a property (for serialization, for example), then you can still encapsulate the behavior by adding an `IsSingleAccount` boolean property to `People` and make the `Address` getter check that and return one value or the other.

```
public class People
{
    public bool IsSingleAccount { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }

    private string _address;
    public string Address
    {
        set => _address = value;
        get => IsSingleAccount ? State : _address;
    }
}
```

That approach isn't as "clean" because `People` needs to track information about stuff that is an external concern, and your consuming code needs to go to extra steps to change that property on all instances. This is an example of a design problem known as a "leaky abstraction".